# Why isn't this button working?

Tags: html

I'm a bit of a rookie programmer, I started a html website recently. It is going to be a project between my friend and I. It will mainly feature flash games, but I added a "Chat" feature from a website called "chatbutton.com". On the left side of the screen there is three buttons, "Games", "Chat", and "About". When I am on the "Games" and "About" pages, all the buttons work perfectly fine, but when I am on the "Chat" page, the "Games" button dosen't seem to work. Here is the code for the chat page:

```
<HTML>
<HEADER>
    <TITLE>CBgames.com</TITLE>
</HEADER>
<BODY bgcolor=#474747 text=#FFFFFF>
    <CENTER>
        <img src="siteimages/title.gif">
    </CENTER>
    <table>
<tr>
    <td><img 
    <a href=file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/games.html>
        <img src="siteimages/gamesbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseovergamesbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/gamesbutton.gif'" /><br>
    <a href=file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/chat.html>
        </br><img src="siteimages/chatbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseoverchatbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/chatbutton.gif'" /><br>
    <a href=file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/about.html>
        </br><img src="siteimages/aboutbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseoveraboutbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/aboutbutton.gif'" /><br>
</br></td>
    <td><iframe name="CHATBUTTON_CHATBOX" id="CHATBUTTON_CHATBOX" src="https://www.chatbutton.com/chatroom/18374628/" width="1500" height="700" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"><a href="https://www.chatbutton.com/chatroom/18374628/">Enter Chat Room</a></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CHBT_channel="18374628";
        CHBT_profanityfilter="1";
        CHBT_position="inline";
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.chatbutton.com/c.js">
        </script>
    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</BODY>
```

FIXED IT: I accidently wrote `<img` in line 11

Comment: Close your anchor tags

Comment: *"It will mainly feature flash games"* - did you start it 15 years ago?

Comment: you foget to close the <a> tag; like : `<a href="google.com">link to google</a> blabla...`

Comment: You're not closing any of your anchor tags. You should have `<a href="blah.html">blah...</a>`

Comment: Incidentally, where are you learning HTML from? The `center` tag is deprecated; you should be using a `div` and using CSS to center the content.

Comment: I have closed your new question and merged it with this one. **Please do not post the same question twice.** Also, your question has already been answered many times in the comments and in the four good answers that you have received. You should mark one of those answers as the accepted answer. If you need to request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, when you make a tag (most times) such as `<a>`, you have to close it. In your code, you create an `<a>`:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/about.html">
```

but never close it, so the table is included inside of the link. To solve this problem, close all of your `<a>`'s as follows:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/games.html">
    <img src="siteimages/gamesbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseovergamesbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/gamesbutton.gif'" />
</a><br>
<a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/chat.html">
    <img src="siteimages/chatbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseoverchatbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/chatbutton.gif'" />
</a><br>
<a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/htmlwebsite/about.html">
    <img src="siteimages/aboutbutton.gif" onmouseover="this.src='siteimages/mouseoveraboutbutton.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='siteimages/aboutbutton.gif'" />
</a><br>
```

Also, don't forget to put your file path for your `href` in quotes (`"`). And, there's no need to close `<br>` separately. You really don't need to close them at all.

**EDIT:** You have part of an `img` tag before your `<a>`'s. Either delete that or make it into something.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you forgot to close your `<a>` tags with an ending `</a>` tag. So your browser still thinks the table is part of the hyperlinked section.

Side note: put your file path in quotations after the href=

Answer (score 2):

You have a `<img` partial tag before your first link.

Also, you need to close your `<a...>` tags with `</a>` after the `<img>`.

Note that you are referencing files that are on your local computer, so obviously no one else will be able to see them.

You might want to run your code through an HTML validator.